# Adding multiple elements of a single columns of dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, rowsum

**dataframe = ax**

```
Col1
0.98 0.076 0.09
0.81 0.01  0.378
0.12 0.33 0.001
```

I want to add these multiple elements of a single row which are separated by space in python such that my output be like

```
   Col1                    Summm
0.98 0.076 0.09        0.98+0.076+0.09          
0.81 0.01  0.378       0.81+0.01+0.378
0.12 0.33 0.001        0.12+0.33+0.001
```

I have tried this

```
summ = numpy.sum(array[0:len(ax),1:len(ax[0])],axis=1).tolist()
```

but this doesnt giv me proper output
Any help would be much appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Is the datatype of Col1 string?

Comment: You can make an iterable over the rows and use the following
`numpy.sum([float(i) for i in str.split(Col1
,  '  ')])`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
df.assign(Summm=df.Col1.str.split('\s+',expand=True).astype(float).sum(1))
```

Output:

```
               Col1  Summm
0   0.98 0.076 0.09  1.146
1  0.81 0.01  0.378  1.198
2   0.12 0.33 0.001  0.451
```

Comment: This is good but,m but this solved my problem col1.sum(axis = 1);;Thanks anyways :)